# Finding a variable values inside a div class with Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find longitudes and latitudes in this `html` code:

```
<div class="map-outer-wrap">
    <div class="map-wrap" data-zoom="15" style="height:500px;" data-latitude="37.4418834" data-longitude="-122.14301949999998" data-style="color">
        <div data-latitude="37.4418834" data-longitude="-122.14301949999998"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/?q=37.4418834,-122.14301949999998&z=10" rel="no-follow" class="overlay-link" target="_blank">View on Google Map</a>
</div>
```

(The full page is here: https://www.towncity.com/property/whole-hotel-for-sale-in-riverside-area/)

Not exactly knowing where to start to actually get to `data-latitude` and `data-longitude`, I tried to narrow down my search to get to the closest div (`map-wrap`), but even this returns an empty list.

```
parser = LinkParser()
data, links = parser.getLinks("https://www.towncity.com/property/whole-hotel-for-sale-in-riverside-area/)
lnglat = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml").findAll("div", {"class": "map-wrap"}).text
```

What's the proper way to retrieve the values of `data-latitude` and `data-longitude` in this page?

Answer (score 4):

You can access the attributes like key-value pairs

**Ex:**

```
s = """
<div class="map-outer-wrap">
    <div class="map-wrap" data-zoom="15" style="height:500px;" data-latitude="37.4418834" data-longitude="-122.14301949999998" data-style="color">
        <div data-latitude="37.4418834" data-longitude="-122.14301949999998"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/?q=37.4418834,-122.14301949999998&z=10" rel="no-follow" class="overlay-link" target="_blank">View on Google Map</a>
</div>"""


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
print( soup.find("div", class_="map-wrap")["data-latitude"] )
print( soup.find("div", class_="map-wrap")["data-longitude"] )
```

**Output:**

```
37.4418834
-122.14301949999998
```

Comment: Thanks! this works great on the short example, but not on the webpage itself, why would that be?

Comment: More precisely, it doesn't work with "soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")", with data = parser.getLinks("https://www.towncity.com/property/whole-hotel-for-sale-in-riverside-area/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

s = requests.get("https://www.towncity.com/property/whole-hotel-for-sale-in-riverside-area/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(s.content, "lxml")
print(soup.find("div", class_="map-wrap")["data-latitude"])
print(soup.find("div", class_="map-wrap")["data-longitude"])
```

output:

```
37.4418834
-122.14301949999998
```